# How can I permanently uninstall the fingerprint driver in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, device-manager, fingerprint, biometrics

Whenever I uninstall it, it comes back when I reboot, and I'd like to make it gone forever. Googling for a while hasn't turned up anything -- I'm only finding threads about rolling back or temporarily uninstalling it.

Answer (score 1):

The driver will always come back so there is no solution on that front.

Turn Fingerprint OFF in Windows 10 Settings, Accounts, Sign In options. Turn it off there and it will stay off. I do that here on my machine (FP reader is not reliable enough so I do not use it).

Comment: Sure, but is there any way at all to remove it for good? With a utility, by editing the registry  -- anything at all? It seems like I should be able to remove it -- it's not a vital component or anything.

Comment: You cannot do it by drivers, but my solution above works permanently unless I re-enable it.

Comment: "Is there any way at all to remove it for good?" - All you can do is block a device driver. However, that only applies to that specific version of the driver, if a new driver is released you would have to block that also.  Microsoft released a utility to block a device driver.

Comment: I know with my own machine, that turning the FP off in Windows Settings survives FP driver updates.

Comment: OK, thanks. How can I block a device driver? I've just googled it, but I'm only getting results for blocking driver installation, which isn't the same thing (right)?

Comment: Microsoft is working toward automating all driver updates, so I do not think that will work

Comment: "Microsoft released a utility to block a device driver." and that utility would be?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you can deactivate biometrical hardware in the BIOS/UEFI of the system. One other solution might be using group policies, but I can’t really help you on that one, you will need to google it or ask another question here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try those.